# Inserting a Component Link in RTF via Experience Manager Hangs

Tags: dxa, web8.5, experience-manager, rtf

I'm attempting to add a Component link to a RTF via Experience Manager. I highlight the text I intend to update and then from the ribbon: Insert > Hyperlink > Type: Component and "Browse", this opens up a library on the left hand side but it's simply hangs with "Loading..."

Checking the Network tab, I can see multiple API calls (i.e. `GetList`, `GetListActivityInstances`, `GetListPublishedTo`, etc.) that returns response (200 status). Inspecting these response, I can see a list of components that I'd expect to see displayed on the library to the left.

Things that I've checked:

- Ensure no console errors
- Check `cd_client.log` and found no relevant errors
- Edit the RTF text and add external links successfully (DXA XPM markup setup correctly)
- Inspect SDL Web documentation for Experience Manager
- My user is an administrator group

I'm using SDL Web 8 Cloud (version 8.6) with DXA 1.7.

Is there anything else that I could check to move this forward?

Comment: You could try clearing your browser's cache and also try it in different browsers. Just to see if it makes a difference and to help isolate the problem.

Comment: Maybe also check the XPM BluePrint context settings and the where those items are loading from. Definitely log a Support ticket to help work out the problem.

Comment: I've tested it in different browsers and clearing my cache but I'm still having the same issue. XPM BluePrint Context Settings for editable page are loading items from the correct publication. I've raised a support ticket with SDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL's R&D Team have released a hotfix (XPM_8.6.0.12993.zip) which have resolved the issue encountered above.